# Grafana on Terraform

Tags: terraform, grafana

I am trying to install Grafana with TimescaleDB using Terraform. Everything with TimescaleDB worked flawlessly, however the Grafana block seems to be completely ignored by Terraform. This is the code I am using to enable Grafana:

```
provider "grafana" {
  url  = "http://localhost:3000/"
  auth = "test:test"
}
```

I am on Terraform 0.13.4 and my `required_providers` block includes Grafana:

```
grafana = {
  source = "grafana/grafana"
}
```

Unlike when I install Grafana through the console, no grafana files are created, `grafana-cli` is not installed, and I get errors trying to use grafana with subsequent `resource` blocks in Terraform so it seems to me that the only issue is with Terraform, and it is just choosing not to install Grafana at all.

What is going on here? I am pretty new to Terraform so it could be that I am missing something obvious...

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding your intentions here, but I want to note that this `grafana` Terraform provider is for configuring a Grafana server that's already installed and running, not for installing Grafana for the first time. You'll need to install Grafana some other way before using Terraform to configure it.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense. So if my terraform was setting everything up from scratch, how would Grafana get installed then? Would it have to be done using `remote-exec`?

Comment: Installing software in virtual machines is typically outside of Terraform's scope, but some options include preparing an AMI ahead of time with Grafana already installed, or using cloud-init in a generic AMI to install some software, or [as a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) you can use provisioners.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, what the [Grafana Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs/resources/data_source) tries to do is connect directly to an existing Grafana instance, based on the URL and the auth token.

Terraform 'can' be used to deploy a running version of Grafana OSS software into a VM, but you will effectivelly be deploying the [Grafana Docker Container Image](https://grafana.com/grafana/download?edition=oss&platform=docker)  using terraform, just like any other service. So every other part of the deployment setup has be pre-configured.

Also note that Grafana will require a persistent configuration database. While the container image includes a sample database for testing, without a properly configured persistent database all the data will be flushed out when the container restarts.